# How to identify "Safari can't open page" in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, safari

Sometimes, Safari shows a "Safari can't open page" screen when visiting my website.

I want to be able to identify this error in Google Analytics. This way I'm able to see how often this problem occurs.

Can I implement this in Google Analytics? If so, how?

Note that the URL of the page does not change when this screen is shown. So simply checking for a condition such as "URL contains ..." in Google Analytics won't work.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is this your landing page or some intermediate page? If intermediate page you can create goal and check reverse-lookup report or goal funnel report.

Comment: Sadly it's the landing page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page doesn't load, then the Analytics code won't run either. So you won't be able to track it.